# iText incompatibility issue, Works on Internet Explorer, but not on Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, adobe, itext, incompatibility

Good morning,

I would like to know whether there is a iText compatibility issue with Firefox or Chrome. I am creating a self-printing pdf document, embedding javascript in it. This javascript is a function call that calls to a .js file located in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\Javascripts

The thing is that I can print it properly from Internet Explorer, but not Firefox nor Chrome. So I would like to know whether there is compatibility issue between this elements. I'm using the following:

- Windows 7
- itext 2.0.2
- Firefox 19
- Chrome 25
- Internet explorer 9

I've also seen that my application is not calling the .js, as if it couldn't find it. I know this because I have added a dummy alert at the beginning of the .js. This works perfectly for IE, but not for the other browsers

Thank you

Comment: How is the PDF actually displayed in Firefox or Chrome? Doesn't Chrome rely on a built-in PDF viewer and Firefox on PDF.js? Neither of them is likely to access data in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\Javascripts`... Furthermore counting on JavaScript been enabled in PDF viewers generally is a shaky foundation to implement one's use cases on...

Comment: I don't display the PDF. The purpose of the javascript is to print straightforward the document. I have been researching more and I have found that if I set in firefox the Options -> Applications -> Portable Document Format (PDF) => Set as "Use Adobe Reader (default)", it works partially. With "partially" I mean that now it shows me the form in which I can choose the printer and print afterwards. Although not the desired behaviour, it's much better!

Comment: Chrome should have a button to the same effect.

Comment: I have found the root of the problem, using the Process Monitor 3.03, in order to monitor the different accesses to the .js file. I have compared the IO calls that are performed both in IE and Firefox, and the problem is that the antivirus (Sophos) is blocking the access to the file, so firefox can't execute the script. I haven't solved the problem itself, but at least now I know the root. Thank you mkl for your help. Regards: Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or not but I was getting spacing issues with FF native reader so a sentence that had an  tag (noted below as VARIABLE) read like this on Adobe

```
"This has spaces between a VARIABLE"
```

But read like this on FF native reader
`"This has spaces between aVARIABLE"` (no space between the variable)

I was using the Unicode character   to insert spaces between my  tags but it turns out this was causing the issue. Also, If I just put the variable on a new line with a space on the line before, that seemed to work too

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js doesn't completely support automatic printing, but the print dialog should automatically come up starting with Firefox 20 as long as you used the standard print() function.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843342